# How is the Combinatorial proof derived?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Could somebody explain how this statement is derived?

$${m+1\choose{k+1}} = \sum_{i=0}^{m-k} {k+i\choose{k}}$$

This is similar to

> $\binom{m+1}{k+1}=\sum_{i=0}^m \binom{i}{k}$

but I am stuck as to how this has evolved into my original post.

Comment: There is no $r$ in the second summation?

Comment: There's something wrong here.  You'e not using the index of summation $r$ inside the sum.  Also, $m$ doesn't appear on the right-hand side.

Comment: Do you mean $i$ or $r$ for the dummy variabel?

Comment: Is the index of summation supposed to be $i$?

Comment: Ammended now. It should be 'm-k' - what has confused me is the presence of i in the right hand side

Comment: it was given to me with i on the right, as shown. If this was changed to r, how would the proof be derived?

Comment: Count $k+1$-element subsets of $\{1,\ldots,m+1\}$ according to their largest elements.

Comment: firstly, notice that:
$$\sum_{i=0}^{m-k}{^{k+i}C_k}=\sum_{i=0}^{m-k}\frac{(k+i)!}{k!i!}$$
and we also know that:
$$(k+i)!=k!\times(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)...(k+i)$$
so we can rewrite it as:
$$\sum_{i=0}^{m-k}\frac{(k+1)(k+2)...(k+i)}{i!}$$
if we look at the terms, we get:
$$1+\frac{(k+1)}{1!}+\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2!}+\frac{(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)}{3!}...$$